# SPFX with React event

Tags: reactjs, spfx

I have this code

```
    import { IListItem } from "../../../model/IListItem";

    export interface IListaMaterialeProps {
    description: string;
    isDarkTheme: boolean;
    environmentMessage: string;
    hasTeamsContext: boolean;
    userDisplayName: string;
    OnElementSelected: (items:IListItem[]) => void;
    OnButtonClick:()=>void;
    }
```

```
    public render(): React.ReactElement<IListaMaterialeProps> {
    return (
    <div className={styles.ListaMateriale}>            
    <div className={styles.ecbParent}>         
    <ListView items={this.state.items}
    iconFieldName="ServerRelativeUrl"
    selectionMode={SelectionMode.multiple}
    selection={this._getSelection}
    viewFields={this.ViewFields}
    compact={true}
    />            
    </div>
    <div className={styles.btnOk}>
    <button onClick={this.props.OnButtonClick}>Conferma</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    );
    }
  
    private _getSelection = (selitems: IListItem[]): void => 
    {
    this.props.OnElementSelected(selitems);
    }
```

```
    export default class ListaMaterialeWebPart extends   BaseClientSideWebPart<IListaMaterialeWebPartProps> 
    {

    private _isDarkTheme: boolean = false;
    private _environmentMessage: string = '';
    private _SelectedItems:IListItem[];

    private _OnConfirm()
    {
    if (this._SelectedItems!=null)
    {
    alert(this._SelectedItems[0].descrizione);
    }
    }

    private _OnElementSelected = (myitems: IListItem[]): void => 
    {
    this._SelectedItems=myitems;
    }

    public render(): void {
    const element: React.ReactElement<IListaMaterialeProps> = React.createElement(
    ListaMateriale,
    {
    description: this.properties.description,
    isDarkTheme: this._isDarkTheme,
    environmentMessage: this._environmentMessage,
    hasTeamsContext: !!this.context.sdks.microsoftTeams,
    userDisplayName: this.context.pageContext.user.displayName,
    OnElementSelected: this._OnElementSelected,
    OnButtonClick:this._OnConfirm
    }
    );

    ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
    
    }
```

but when i click on button i have this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_SelectedItems')
at G5A4.ListaMaterialeWebPart._OnConfirm (ListaMaterialeWebPart.ts:29:14)

error is in function _OnConfirm

why _SelectedItems is not definied in _OnConfirm, but is defined in _OnElementSelected  ?